# Regular Expression Matching Perl for first case of pattern

Tags: perl

I have multiple variables that have strings in the following format:

`some_text_here__what__i__want_here__andthen_some`

I want to be able to assign to a variable the `what__i__want_here` portion of the first variable. In other words, everything after the FIRST double underscore. There may be double underscores in the rest of the string but I only want to take the text after the FIRST pair of underscores.

Ex.

If I have `$var = "some_text_here__what__i__want_here__andthen_some"`, I would like to assign to a new variable only the second part like `$var2 = "what__i__want_here__andthen_some"`

I'm not very good at matching so I'm not quite sure how to do it so it just takes everything after the first double underscore.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I mentioned "I have multiple variables". That was just an example of how the format is. For each of the variables having a string of that format, I would like to take the second portion of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $text = 'some_text_here__what__i__want_here';
# .*?     # Match a minimal number of characters - see "man perlre"
# /s      # Make . match also newline - see "man perlre"
my ($var) =  $text =~ /^.*?__(.*)$/s;
# $var is not defined when there is no __ in the string
print "var=${var}\n" if defined($var);
```

Comment: This does replace matches after double underscore, but for all of them. I just want it to replace matches after the FIRST appearance of a double underscore.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider this an example of where `split`'s third parameter is useful. The third parameter to `split` constrains how many elements to return.  Here is an example:

```
my @examples = (
    'some_text_here__what__i_want_here',
    '__keep_this__part',
    'nothing_found_here',
    'nothing_after__',
);

foreach my $string (@examples) {
    my $want = (split /__/, $string, 2)[1];
    print "$string => ", (defined $want ? $want : ''), "\n";
}
```

The output will look like this:

```
some_text_here__what__i_want_here => what__i_want_here
__keep_this__part => keep_this__part
nothing_found_here =>
nothing_after__ =>
```

This line is a little dense:

```
my $want = (split /__/, $string, 2)[1];
```

Let's break that down:

```
my ($prefix, $want) = split /__/, $string, 2;
```

The `2` parameter tells `split` that no matter how many times the pattern `/__/` could match, we only want to split one time, the first time it's found.  So as another example:

```
my (@parts) = split /#/, "foo#bar#baz#buzz", 3;
```

The `@parts` array will receive these elements: 'foo', 'bar', 'baz#buzz', because we told it to stop splitting after the second split, so that we get a total maximum of three elements in our result.

Back to your case, we set 2 as the maximum number of elements.  We then go one step further by eliminating the need for `my ($throwaway, $want) = ...`. We can tell Perl we only care about the second element in the list of things returned by `split`, by providing an index.

```
my $want = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')[2]; # c, the element at offset 2 in the list.

my $want = (split /__/, $string, 2)[1]; # The element at offset 1 in the list
                                        # of two elements returned by split.
```

Answer (score 0):

You use brackets to capature then reorder the string, the first set of brackets () is $1 in the next part of the substitution, etc ...

```
my $string = "some_text_here__what__i__want_here";
(my $newstring = $string) =~ s/(some_text_here)(__)(what__i__want_here)/$3$2$1/;
print $newstring;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
what__i__want_here__some_text_here
```

Comment: I'm not looking for how to re-order the string. I just edited my question to explain further since.